# Wrong result from scipy.optimize.minimize used on Fortran function using ctypes

Tags: python, scipy, fortran, ctypes

I currently have a Fortran function that I want to optimize using SciPy wrapping it using Ctypes.  Is this possible?  Perhaps I've done something wrong in my implementation.  For example, assume I have:

## cost.f90

```
module cost_fn
  use iso_c_binding, only: c_float
  implicit none

contains

  function sin_2_cos(x,y) bind(c)
      real(c_float) :: x, y, sin_2_cos
      sin_2_cos = sin(x)**2 * cos(y)
  end function sin_2_cos

end module cost_fn
```

that I compile with:

```
gfortran -fPIC -shared -g -o cost.so cost.f90
```

and then try to find a (local) minimum with:

## cost.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from ctypes import *
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as sopt

cost = cdll.LoadLibrary('./cost.so')

cost.sin_2_cos.argtypes = [POINTER(c_float), POINTER(c_float)]
cost.sin_2_cos.restype = c_float

def f2(x):
    return cost.sin_2_cos(c_float(x[0]), c_float(x[1]))
    # return np.sin(x[0])**2 * np.cos(x[1])

# print(f2( [1, 1] ))
# print(f2( [0.5 * np.pi, np.pi] ))

print( sopt.minimize( f2, (1.0, 1.0), options={'disp': True}, tol=1e-8) )
```

I expect a local minimum f2(pi / 2, pi) = -1.  When I call f2 with the cost.sin_2_cos return value, the "minimimum" is just given at the initial guess of (1, 1).  If I call f2 with the "Python" return value, optimize finds the correct minimum.

I've tried redefining sin_2_cos to take dimension(2) array input, but was seeing similar behavior.  Perhaps I need to call sin_2_cos directly with minimize (but then how would I specify c_float for the arguments)?  Any thoughts are appreciated!

Edit: To a comment below, note that the two commented `print(f2(...))` lines produce the expected values.  Thus, I believe the Fortran function is being properly called through the Python f2 function.

Comment: You must add at least (there might be other problems) the 'value' attribute to your arguments, see http://www.fortran90.org/src/best-practices.html#using-ctypes

Comment: Why must I do this?  If I uncomment the calls to f2, it works correctly.  The webpage you listed doesn't make it clear why 'value' is there nor does it use it in the earlier `iso_c_binding` example.  Note that adding value doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: I changed the title to something more specific. I assume "Yes, it can." would not be an acceptable answer for you.

Comment: Have you checked that the function gives correct values when called from Python?

Comment: When I uncomment the two `print(f2(...))` lines, I get the expected values (0.382573664188385 and -1.0) with the code I posted.

Comment: @Pierre, note that adding `value` prevents correct behavior when using the solution provided below by Warren Weckesser when converting from float to double.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't see directly that you were using pointers in the ctypes part. As the problem was solved elsewhere I did not bother adding the correction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your Fortran code uses single precision floating point values (i.e. 32 bit floats).  (In C, `float` is single precision and `double` is double precision.)  The default method used by `scipy.optimize.minimize()` uses finite differences to approximate the derivatives of the function.  That is, to estimate the derivative `f'(x0)`, it computes `(f(x0+eps) - f(x0))/eps`, where `eps` is the step size.  The default step size that it uses to compute the finite differences is approximately 1.49e-08.  Unfortunately, this value is smaller than the spacing of single precision values around the value 1.  So when the minimizer adds `eps` to 1, the result is still 1. That means the function is evaluated at the same point, and the finite difference result is 0.  That's a condition for the minimum, so the solver decides it is done.

The solver option `eps` sets the finite difference step size.  Set it to something larger than 1.19e-7.  For example, if I use `options={'disp': True, 'eps': 2e-6}`, I get a solution.

By the way, you can find that value, 1.19e-7, by using `numpy.finfo()`:

```
In [4]: np.finfo(np.float32(1.0)).eps
Out[4]: 1.1920929e-07
```

You'll also get a solution if you use the option `method='nelder-mead'` in the `minimize()` function.  That method does not rely on finite differences.

Finally, you could convert the Fortran code to use double precision:

```
module cost_fn
  use iso_c_binding, only: c_double
  implicit none

contains

  function sin_2_cos(x,y) bind(c)
      real(c_double) :: x, y, sin_2_cos
      sin_2_cos = sin(x)**2 * cos(y)
  end function sin_2_cos

end module cost_fn
```

Then change the Python code to use `ctypes.c_double` instead of `ctypes.c_float`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the clear explanation and two alternative solutions.  I can confirm that both approaches work and I've accepted your solution.

Interestingly, I looked through the [scipy.optimize.minimize documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize) but couldn't find the `eps` argument so I didn't identify that as a cause.

Comment: I should have added to the prior comment that I looked at the base documentation but didn't dive into the method-specific documentation.  Had I done so, I would have come across `eps`.  However, focusing on this level of detail removes some of the abstraction of just calling `minimize`.  Hopefully future readers can learn from my mistake / lack of diligence.